# MySQL максимально похожие значения

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли на MySQL реализовать такую выборку.
К примеру, есть таблица со значениями:

```
111258
200345
409879
111263
111599
214689
409822
```

Можно ли составить SELECT так, чтобы запрос выдавал в ответ сгруппированные наиболее одинаковые значения.
К примеру, из предыдущих значений получить такой результат:

```
111258
111263
409879
409822
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/342434/ направление надеюсь укажет :)

Comment: Как только будет сформулирован чёткий математический критерий, по которому для любой пары чисел можно будет сказать, соответствуют ли они понятию "наиболее одинаковые значения", так сразу задача и решится. Хотя как-то непонятно - то ли статистическая обработка полимодальки, то ли кластеризация...